# what does this use of delegate mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, delegates

I can't understand why delegate is used here:

```
List<string> temp_list = new List<string>();
string[] temp_array;
temp_array = Array.ConvertAll(arr_DL[m], delegate (int j) { return j.ToString(); });
temp_list.AddRange(temp_array.ToList());
```

the code is supposed to convert the array to list. 
Can someone help explain the use of delegate here?

Answer (score 1):

That because it's the second parameter of [ConvertAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It represent how each element in initial `Array` should be converted:

> A Converter<TInput, TOutput> that converts each element from one type to another type.

So your delegate sais "convert each `int` `j` to `string` by performing `j.ToString();`"

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
delegate (int j) { return j.ToString(); }
```

creates so-called "anonymous method" as second parameter `TOutput`, which used to convert int variable input into String then passes it into `Array.ConvertAll()` method. Anonymous methods used widely on C# 2.0, where in C# 3.0 they substituted with lambda expression like this:

```
delegate String output (int j);
String output = x => { x.ToString(); }
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx

CMIIW.